# inconsistent value of input in react when removing dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I can't get this simple adding and removing input right, when I have 3 fields, I fill the all the input, I clicked delete on the 2nd item, I suppose to see value 1 and 2 but it doesn't?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rows: [
        {
          id: 1
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  addRow = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        rows: [...this.state.rows, { id: this.state.rows.length + 1 }]
      },
      () => console.log(this.state.rows)
    );
  };

  deleteRow = id => {
    console.log(id);
    const { rows } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      rows: rows.filter(row => row.id !== id)
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { rows } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {rows.map(o => (
          <div>
            <input key={o.id} id={o.id} placeholder={"text"} type="text" />
            <div
              style={{ display: "inline-block" }}
              onClick={e => this.deleteRow(o.id)}
            >
              x
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
        <button onClick={this.addRow}>add</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/kwkoj33o2v

Answer (score 0):

The values of the inputs need to be **controlled** for it to stick. If they're not controlled, values would only persist until the end of that input's lifecycle, and since they're being recreated on render if they have their position changed, they lose the typed value.

This should work:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import uuid from "uuid";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentId: 1,
      rows: [
        {
          id: uuid(),
          value: '',
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  addRow = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        rows: [...this.state.rows, { id: uuid(), value: '' }]
      },
      () => console.log(this.state.rows)
    );
  };

  deleteRow = id => {
    console.log(id);
    const { rows } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      rows: rows.filter(row => row.id !== id)
    });
  };

  handleChangeRow = (id) => ({target: {value}}) => this.setState({rows: this.state.rows.map(row => row.id === id ? {...row, value} : row)})

  render() {
    const { rows } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {rows.map(o => (
          <div>
            <input value={o.value} key={o.id} id={o.id} placeholder={"text"} type="text" 
onChange={this.handleChangeRow(o.id)}/>
            <div
              style={{ display: "inline-block" }}
              onClick={e => this.deleteRow(o.id)}
            >
              x
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
        <button onClick={this.addRow}>add</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/p785wv1z7m

Edit: Changed to the IDs to use uuid to guarantee uniqueness, but to be fair you don't generally need to assign ids to an array of components in the state, as stated in the other answer. You can get away with just using the indexes, or if you already have an innate ID in the component data, that's also fine to use.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't know what you mean.

Comment: See Austio's answer.

Comment: Oh, I see. 2 different issues then, completely missed that.

Answer (score 0):

1 bug for sure is that when you are setting the ID of the items to the length.  So if you add 2, delete the first one, then add one, you will have two with the same id.

```
[{id: 1}]
// Push one
[{id: 1}, {id: 2}]
// Delete value of 1
[{id: 2}]
// Push one
[{id: 2}, {id: 2}] // wooops!
```

I would do add/remove based on the index of the array in this case instead to solve.

Comment: which line? so what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from values not being saved across state changes, inputs are being assigned incorrect IDs which leads to several having the same ID and being deleted together. Here's a simple readable fix with a `saveValue` method for saving input values on each change:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentId: 1,
      rows: [
        {
          id: 1,
          value: ''
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  addRow = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        currentId: this.state.currentId + 1,
        rows: [...this.state.rows, { id: this.state.currentId + 1, value: '' }]
      },
      console.log(this.state.rows)
    );
  };

  deleteRow = id => {
    console.log(id);
    let rows = this.state.rows;
    this.setState({
      rows: rows.filter(row => row.id !== id)
    });
  };

  saveValue = (e, id) => {
    let rows = this.state.rows;
    rows[id - 1].value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ rows: rows });
  }

  render() {
    const { rows } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {rows.map(o => (
          <div key={o.id}>
            <input id={o.id} value={o.value} placeholder={"text"} type="text" onChange={e => this.saveValue(e, o.id)}/>
            <div
              style={{ display: "inline-block" }}
              onClick={() => this.deleteRow(o.id)}
            >
              x
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
        <button onClick={this.addRow}>add</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/qqvvq27k36

Also note that when you use `map` to add elements, the top-most element inside `map` (the `div` in this case) needs to have the `key` attribute, not the input element. That wasn't breaking anything, but it's good practice to follow that rule.

Comment: Thought I saved my changes. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to @Bernardo Siqueira's answer, but:

- Simplifies the Fields to use the field `name` as the `id`
- Shows the current structure/values of the `this.state.Fields` array
- Prevents the user from removing a field if there's only one
- Adds an option to submit the form

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/qm96vv8z9

**index.js**

```
import map from "lodash/map";
import filter from "lodash/filter";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import FieldInput from "./FieldInput";
import "uikit/dist/css/uikit.min.css";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    fieldsCount: 1,
    Fields: [
      {
        name: "Field0",
        value: ""
      }
    ]
  };

  handleChange = name => ({ target: { value } }) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      Fields: map(
        this.state.Fields,
        field => (field.name === name ? { ...field, value } : field)
      )
    }));
  };

  showFieldValues = fields => {
    return map(fields, ({ value }) => value);
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    alert(`Field value(s): ${this.showFieldValues(this.state.Fields)}`);
  };

  addField = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      Fields: [
        ...this.state.Fields,
        {
          name: `Field${this.state.fieldsCount}`,
          value: ""
        }
      ],
      fieldsCount: this.state.fieldsCount + 1
    }));
  };

  deleteField = name => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      Fields: filter(this.state.Fields, field => field.name !== name)
    }));
  };

  render = () => (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
      <h1>Dynamic Field Creation</h1>
      <FieldInput
        {...this.state}
        deleteField={this.deleteField}
        handleChange={this.handleChange}
      />
      <button
        type="button"
        style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
        className="uk-button uk-button-primary"
        onClick={this.addField}
      >
        Add Field
      </button>
      <button type="submit" className="uk-button uk-button-secondary">
        Submit
      </button>
      <pre style={{ textAlign: "left", height: 300, scrollY: "auto" }}>
        <code>{JSON.stringify(this.state.Fields, null, 4)}</code>
      </pre>
    </form>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**FieldInput.js**

```
import map from "lodash/map";
import React from "react";

export default ({ Fields, handleChange, deleteField }) =>
  map(Fields, ({ name }, key) => (
    <div key={name} style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
      <input
        className="uk-input"
        onChange={handleChange(name)}
        name={name}
        placeholder="Write something..."
        type="text"
        value={Fields[key].value}
        style={{ width: 300, marginRight: 20 }}
      />
      <button
        className="uk-button uk-button-danger"
        style={{ display: "inline-block" }}
        onClick={() => deleteField(name)}
        disabled={Fields.length === 1}
      >
        <i className="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" />
      </button>
    </div>
  ));
```